# Creating wifi network using multiple windows phone devices?

Tags: networking, windows-phone, wifi

I have this problem. I would like to create a multiplayer game aplication for Windows Phone platform. I wanted to offer some really good action for let's say 4 people. One phone would be hosting the game and other 3 would connect to the host. To do this, I was thinking I'm gonna need to connect the phones with Windows Phone 8 OS (or even Windows Phone 7?) to one network using their wifi connectivity.

So my question is - is it possible to create a wifi network between 4 devices with Windows Phone 8 OS (or WP7?)?

Answer (score 3):

On Windows Phone 7 (it is supported on Windows Phone 8 but you would have to build your project under Windows Phone 7 (for XNA support)), the following types of networking are supported for XNA Game Studio titles:

Xbox LIVE access through Gamer Services. This is available only to developers who have registered with Microsoft for Xbox LIVE on Windows Phone access. For more information about becoming a registered Xbox LIVE on Windows Phone developer, go to developer.windowsphone.com.

Web requests using the Hypertext Transport Protocol (HTTP). This is available to all applications on Windows Phone.

Push notifications. Push notifications are also implemented through HTTP (client and server) and are available to all applications on Windows Phone.

Also, Microsoft has a few examples of game networking on their [Windows Phone Dev Center Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps) site. Like this [Tic-Tac-Toe Over Sockets Example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Tic-Tac-Toe-Over-Sockets-cffbffd3) which contains client and server source code or this [Rock Paper Scissors Example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Multicast-Sockets-Sample-51190c11).

Lastly, keep in mind that if you start a new game project targeted specifically for Windows 8 use the following tips when considering XNA related items:

XNA Game Studio 4.0 apps that target Windows Phone OS 7.1 remain fully supported and continue to run on Windows Phone 8 devices.

You can continue to develop and maintain new or existing XNA Framework apps that target Windows Phone OS 7.1.

You can’t upgrade existing XNA Framework apps that target Windows Phone OS 7.1 to target Windows Phone OS 8.0.

You can’t create new XNA Framework apps that target Windows Phone OS 8.0.

When you select an XNA Game Studio 4.0 project template, you can only choose Windows Phone OS 7.1 as the target operating system.

You can use certain XNA Framework assemblies in apps that target Windows Phone OS 8.0.

You can reference and use the following XNA Framework assemblies in apps that target Windows Phone OS 8.0. You can’t reference or use other XNA Framework assemblies that aren’t in this list in apps that target Windows Phone OS 8.0.

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.dll
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.dll
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServicesExtensions.dll
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.dll
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.dll
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.MediaLibraryExtensions.dll
```

Source: [Microsoft MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221582.aspx) [XNA Framework and Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)